# Pushing tags to github no longer causes travis to rebuild?

Tags: travis-ci

For at least several weeks I've been using tags to deploy releases to github. I commit some changes, travis builds cleanly (or not, in which case I push some more changes :-) ), I decide it's ready to release, I create and push a tag. Travis builds again and the deploy script puts the release artifacts on github. It's marvelous.

If you look at the build history here, for example: https://travis-ci.org/ndw/xmlcalabash1-xmlunit/builds you'll see what I mean.

Yesterday afternoon, I decided to release so I pushed a 1.1.1 tag. You can see that on github: https://github.com/ndw/xmlcalabash1-xmlunit/releases but travis didn't see the commit of the tag or didn't react to it or something.

I did this on several repositories and the result was the same in each one (and had also previously always worked). I deleted and repushed the tag, but that had no effect either.

I don't think I changed "anything else". The only difference I can think of is that several hours elapsed between the last code checkin and the tag checkin.

Clues most humbly solicited.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be the case that if the last non-tag commit push used [ci skip] then pushing the tag won't cause travis to rebuild. That was...confusing.